# Google Sheets Query - merge column data to rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to merge data (name + value/s) in different rows based on another column (name). See example below:

name | value

A | ab

A | ac

A | ad

B | bc

B | bd

I want the output to be like this (in rows and concatenated in one cell):

A ab ac ad

B bc bd

Is this possible with Google sheets query?

Comment: Please share a link to a sample spreadsheet with some realistic data and your hand-entered results where you'd like to see a formula produce those results.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. I'd like to have the result in column C: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dlwv71sgJSExgaYdJFpLGosMcWZoP04xPD4Hx8JKhyQ/edit#gid=0

Comment: Do you need the results lined up with the first occurrence of the same name from Col A exactly as shown?

Comment: Not really. As long as the result shows first the value in Col A then followed by Col B. Even if the values in Col B are rearranged, that's fine as long as all values in Col B are grouped by Col A and in one cell.

Comment: Hi! I made it public. Feel free to edit. Thanks so much!

Comment: I have added two solutions for you with a note for each. I will post the main formula in a reply post below.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me with this. Both formulas work for me.

Comment: You are welcome, and I'm glad to hear it. Please take a moment, then, to mark my post below (which contains the formulas) as "Best Answer" so that the other volunteer contributors know this post has been successfully answered, and so that future site visitors can more easily find this solution if it matches their own needs or search terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a new sheet ("Erik Help"). To achieve the exact results you wanted:

`=ArrayFormula({"Result";IF(A2:A="",,IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A,A2:A,ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A))>1,,VLOOKUP(A2:A&"*",REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({A2:B},  "Select MAX(Col2) where Col2 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col2 PIVOT Col1"),, 9^9)),"~")),"[,\s]+$",""),1,FALSE)))})`

This is a more complex formula than I can typically share on this free forum, so I will need to leave the understanding of the formula to you and others who may be interested.

I also left a second formula, which shows only the aggregated list, as a "bonus" for you:

`=ArrayFormula({"Aggregated List";REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({A2:B},  "Select MAX(Col2) where Col2 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col2 PIVOT Col1"),, 9^9)),"~")),"[,\s]+$","")})`